# /dev/sda1 100% Mysql to blame?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I have a an API running that receives raw binaries, processes them, and then stores metadata about the bins in a mysql database. I have been running it for a couple days on a VM. Today the API stopped processing the mySQL commands. After using the command `df-h` the results were:

```
root@mwdb1:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       104G   99G     0 100% /
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  364K  6.3G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1       5.5T   42G  5.2T   1% /data
```

sda1 is at 100%

Comment: You would know where you configured mysql to store the database, and how big it is, so you should know whether or not it's the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Run a `du -x * | sort -n` in your `/` directory. It will show you in which directory your disc space is used. Try this recursively.

Or use `baobab`.

After this you will possibly know if mysql is to blame.